# First row in database not displaying in table with either mysql_fetch_row or mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Though these questions have already been answered and i have tried to follow those, yet the first row from mysql database is not getting displayed in the table. (I have three rows)

Following is my code. Will be very kind of you if you can help. Thank You.

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbreg.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>User Listing</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>Lastname</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regform");
    if(mysql_fetch_row($query) > 0) {
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {




            ?>

            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $result['firstname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['lastname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['address'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['country'];?></td>
                <td><a href="view.php">View</a> /<a href="#"> Edit</a></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` already __fetches__ your first row. And `mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches the __following__ one.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! These are a bit confusing since i am new to php and mysql. Can you guide me to any link / document to get a more clear idea on this?

Comment: All documentation in on `php.net` And you have documentation section on this site too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"if(mysql_fetch_row($query) > 0) {" line is reading already the result-set moving the cursor forward so when code execution gets to the "while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {" line it is already at second row in result-set.
You should remove the "if line" because while will act exactly as you expect.